# what should be the my.cnf file's configuration when working with the huge amount of catalog in magento?

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I am working on **magento version 1.9.1.0 and i have a huge amount of catalog.This is  working on AWS(m3large server) with 2 virtual cpu's and 7.5 GB memory.After reindexing all attributes Home page is not visible and its showing no data received error.Taking too much time to response in other pages too.

Database table sizes is below and my.cnf file's configuration.
how to decrease response time and resolve home page visibility issue.

```
**datbase table sizes in MB 
 1.catalogsearch_fulltext    |    8526.87 |
2.catalog_product_entity_varchar|    2734.56 |
3.catalog_product_entity_text   |    1849.33 |
4.core_url_rewrite    |    1806.23 |
5.catalog_category_product_index    |    1536.00 |
6.catalog_product_index_price    |    1167.97 |
7.catalog_product_index_eav_idx     |    1097.34 |
8.catalog_product_index_price_idx    |    1012.20 |
9.catalog_product_index_price_final_idx    |     987.00 |
10.catalog_product_flat_1    |     826.84 |
11.catalog_product_index_eav    |     766.69 |
12.catalog_product_entity_int    |     765.45 |
13.catalog_category_product_index_idx    |     758.92 |
14.catalog_product_entity_decimal   |     689.39 |
15.catalog_category_product_index_enbl_idx   |     472.77 |
16.catalog_category_anc_products_index_idx    |     418.70 |
17.cataloginventory_stock_item    |     311.42 |
18.catalog_product_entity    |     295.53 |
19.cataloginventory_stock_status_idx    |     158.75 |
20.cataloginventory_stock_status    |     158.75 |
21.catalog_product_entity_media_gallery |     117.30 |
22.catalog_category_product    |      97.17 |
23.catalog_product_website    |      87.16 |
24.catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value    |      35.08 |
25.product_stock   |      27.56 |
26.catalogsearch_result    |      22.55 |
27.log_visitor_info    |      13.52 |
28.log_url_info    |       8.52 |
29.log_url    |       7.55 |
30.report_event    |       7.08 |
31.catalog_category_entity_varchar    |       6.06 |
32.log_visitor    |       5.52 |
33.core_email_template    |       3.56 |

**my.cnf** file's configuration
*# The MySQL database server configuration file.

[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

**# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

**# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
log-queries-not-using-indexes


[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Are you getting any error visible on Home page or in Magento logs

Comment: When I am trying to reindex i am getting this error:-PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228